# load js file in runtime checking whether it is not loaded

Tags: jquery, dynamic

how it can be implemented that- load jquery file dynamically whether it is not loaded???
or if loaded then ignore further load.,.??

thanks

Comment: Why do you need this, by the way?

Comment: for ajax load of html page in ui-tab!!!

Comment: What did you do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
{
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/path/to/your/jquery' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

            if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
            {
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='development-bundle/jquery-1.3.2.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='development-bundle/ui/ui.core.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
            }



   
   
   
   
   $(function(){
                // Datepicker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    
    
    
   });
  </script>


is it posible???

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [getScript](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript#urlcallback). It will load a script file, and a callback function is run when the loading is done.